# Will decreasing the variance of a subset, the global variance also decrease and vice versa?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

While implementing one of our propose algorithm we are assuming that, by decreasing the variance of a subset, the global variance will also decrease considering the global mean value remains same and vice versa.

For example, considering the below list

{1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 5, 6, 5}; $\sigma^2_{Global_{Before}} = 5.1875$ and $\mu_{Global_{Before}} = 3.25$

Now if we consider the subset
{1,6,5}; $\sigma^2_{Local_{Before}} = 4.67$ and $\mu_{Local_{Before}} = 4$

and rearrange the items as below

{4,4,4}; $\sigma^2_{Local_{After}} = 0$ and $\mu_{Local_{After}} = 4$

Thus the global list has been updated as below

{1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 6, 5}; $\sigma^2_{Global_{After}} = 3.4375$ and $\mu_{Global_{After}} = 3.25$

Is it something we need to proof by theorem or it has been already proven? Where can I get the proof or if anyone can give me some guidelines.

Comment: How do you want to decrease the variance? Without giving your method, we can't even say if your claim is correct let alone how to prove it.

Comment: Hi, @AlexR sorry for the delay but I've updated the question to make the point clear. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given any finite set of variables $A = \{ a_1, a_2, \ldots a_n \}$, let
$|A|$, $\mu_A$, $\sigma_A$ be the number, mean and standard derviations of variables in $A$. We have

$$\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{a \in A} a   &= |A| \mu_A\\
\sum\limits_{a \in A} a^2 &= |A| \left(\sigma_A^2 + \mu_A^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
This means if $A$ and $B$ are two disjoint finite set of variables, we have

$$\begin{align}
|A\cup B|\mu_{A\cup B} &= |A| \mu_A + |B| \mu_B\\
|A\cup B|\left(\sigma_{A\cup B}^2 + \mu_{A\cup B}^2\right) &=
|A| \left(\sigma_A^2 + \mu_A^2\right) +
|B| \left(\sigma_B^2 + \mu_B^2\right)
\end{align}
$$
This leads to
$$\sigma_{A\cup B}^2 =
\frac{|A|\sigma_A^2 + |B|\sigma_B^2}{|A\cup B|}
+ \frac{|A||B|}{|A\cup B|^2}(\mu_A - \mu_B)^2
$$
As a consequence, if one reduce the variance $\sigma_A^2$ by keeping
$\mu_A, \mu_B$ and $\sigma_B^2$ all fixed, then the variance of the union, $\sigma_{A\cup B}^2$, also decreases.

Answer (score 2):

In general this will not work. Consider the list

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 5, 6, 5
```

Now reduce the variance of the right hand four terms by changing the list to

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6
```

The overall variance just got worse.

You might argue that if you'd changed it to "5,5,5,5" it'd have gotten better, and that's correct...but just *reducing* variance in a subset won't help, as this example shows.

In general, if you replace each element of a subset by its mean, then you should indeed reduce total variance, because total mean $m$ remains the same, and the sum of square distances to $m$ for things outside the subset remains the same, but the sum of squared distance to $m$ for things INSIDE the subset gets smaller.

Comment: Based on what you said at the end means this will work, right?

Comment: The problem is that you haven't made clear what "this", in "this will work", means. If it means "reducing the variance of the subset", then my example shows that the answer is no. If it's "replace each element of the subset by the mean of the subset," then the answer is "yes".

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I've updated the question now with the same example list that you've provided. I hope this will clarify the point. Thanks again as it helped me understanding how to write a good question :)